# Select character in between slashes --sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have below string.Can some one help me how to select only characters after **`data/`** and before **`cross/`**

```
/dss/data/20131223_155909_7325/Cross-Boundary-Collaboration_Participant_Workbook_v1.4.onepkg
```

Please note **`/dss/data/`** will be consistent but characters may vary after **`7325/`**

Comment: You need "regular expressions" for that. Either you have to do that in a scripting environment or you need to rely on implementation specific sql extensions. That obviously depends on the sql server type you are using, which you did not specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select everything after `/dss/data/` up to next slash `/`

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @string = '/dss/data/20131223_155909_7325/Cross-Boundary-Collaboration_Participant_Workbook_v1.4.onepkg';

SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(@string,'/dss/data/',''), CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(@string,'/dss/data/',''))-1)
```

`20131223_155909_7325` in this example

Answer (score 0):

USE [CHARINDEX and then SUBSTRING](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

EDIT:

This will give you an idea on what to do:

```
DECLARE @URL    VARCHAR(1000)
SET @URL = 'http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tid=58'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@URL, 8, CHARINDEX('/', @URL, 9) - 8) AS [Domain Name],
   REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@URL), CHARINDEX('?', REVERSE(@URL)) + 1,
   CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@URL)) - CHARINDEX('?', REVERSE(@URL)) - 1)) AS [Page Name],
   SUBSTRING(@URL, CHARINDEX('?', @URL) + 1, LEN(@URL)) AS [Query Parameter]
```

Source: click [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=4AB06421-E859-4B5F-A948-0C9640F3108D&tkw=uses-of-the-substring-string-function)

Comment: can you please post some syntax for above string

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(@string,CHARINDEX('data/',@string,1)+5,CHARINDEX('/Cross',@string,1)-CHARINDEX('data/',@string,1)-5)
```